How to convert 2D format to Geo2D format, so that we can use panoply to open/plot an nc file variable?
What is exactly I am missing NC file 1, as compared to NC file 2 --> that will allow me to have it in Geo2D format, compatible with Panoply? I am having no luck so far. See for details on what I have tried so far:
NC file 1
The format (which in Panoply says "2D") that I have looks like this:
float h2o_column(1, 4172, 215);
  :coordinates = "latitude_center longitude_center";
  :_FillValue = 9.96921E36; // double
  :valid_min = 0.0f; // float
  :valid_max = 9.96921E36f; // float
  :_ChunkSizes = 1L, 4172L, 215L; // long
  :standard_name = "water_column";
  :long_name = "Vertically integrated column of water";
  :units = "molec. cm-2";

NC file 2
This is the reference template I am following (but this one is correctly specified as "Geo2D", and can be plotted on a basemap)
float carbonmonoxide_total_column(time=1, scanline=4172, ground_pixel=215);
  :units = "mol m-2";
  :standard_name = "atmosphere_mole_content_of_carbon_monoxide";
  :long_name = "Vertically integrated CO column";
  :coordinates = "longitude latitude";
  :ancillary_variables = "carbonmonoxide_total_column_precision";
  :multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2 = 6.022141E19f; // float
  :_FillValue = 9.96921E36f; // float
  :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 4172U, 215U; // uint


It is likely that coordinates of first are not https://cfconventions.org/ compatible.
